# Selecting App in Parse Cloud Code Error

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to set up the command line tool so I can use Cloud Code for my Android Application. I go through the process located here

https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code/windows

but when I log in and go to select my application it does not show any applications. Instead it only shows "1.Results" and not any of my applications. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered. This happens when using an outdated Windows CLI for Parse. The updated CLI can be found here.

https://parse.com/docs/downloads